# AttributeError: 'AcceptInvite' object has no attribute 'email'

Tags: django, forms, unit-testing, attributeerror

Im doing some unit testing in my Django project, and am getting error
`"AttributeError: 'SignUp' object has no attribute 'email'"`
when I run this test.

```
def test_signup(self):
        response = self.c.post('/accounts/signup/', {'email': 'test@test.com', 'password': 'test123', 'password_conf': 'test123',
                                                     'org_name': 'test org', 'org_username': 'test org username', 'invite': '4013'})
        code = response.status_code
        self.assertTrue(code == 200)
```

The view this is testing simply takes a signup form, and creates a new account with it.

```
def signup(request):
    # """Register a new account with a new org."""

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUp(request.POST)

        if not form.email or not form.password:
            raise Exception("Email and Password are required")
        if form.password != form.password_conf:
            raise  Exception("Password does not match confirmation")
        if not form.org_name or not form.org_username:
            raise Exception('Organization name and username are required')
        if not form.invite:
            raise Exception('Invitation code is required')

        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data

            email = cleaned_data['email']
            password = cleaned_data['password']
            org_name = cleaned_data['org_name']
            org_username = cleaned_data['org_username']
            invite_token = cleaned_data['invite']

            invitation = OrgInvite.objects.get(token=invite_token)

            if invitation.used:
                raise Exception("invitation code is invalid")

            account = Account(email=email, password=password)
            account.save()

            org = Org(org_name=org_name, org_username=org_username)
            org.save()

            invitation.used = False
            invitation.save()

            login(request)

            # Send Email

            md = mandrill.Mandrill(settings.MANDRILL_API_KEY)
            t = invite_token.replace(' ', '+')
            url = "https://www.humanlink.co/verify/{}".format(t)
            message = {
                'global_merge_vars': [
                    {'name': 'VERIFICATION_URL', 'content': url},
                ],
                'to': [
                    {'email': account.email},
                ],
            }
            message['from_name'] = message.get('from_name',     'Humanlink')
            message['from_email'] = message.get('from_email',    'support@humanlink.co')
            try:
                md.messages.send_template(
                    template_name='humanlink-welcome', message=message,
                    template_content=[], async=True)
            except mandrill.Error as e:
                logging.exception(e)
                raise Exception('Unknown service exception')
```

The Signup form has an email field, and the data in request.POST should have the email I am sending it with my Client's post method being used in my unit test, so I am really not sure why it still wouldn't have an 'email' attribute.

Form:

```
class SignUp(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField()
    password_conf = forms.CharField()
    org_name = forms.CharField()
    org_username = forms.CharField()
    invite = forms.CharField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code suffers from multiple errors. To address your question, in your view method `signup` you were creating a form, but you shouldn't do `form.email` or `form.password` because that's not how django handles form data.

Other related issues, first, you need to call `form.is_valid()` before you could get any data from form object. Even so, you should use `form.cleaned_data['email']` to access the form data.

Secondly. You shouldn't do empty check like that. If you put:

```
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
```

django will automatically verify the emptiness for you already.

Thirdly, raising Exception in views.py method doesn't get your form to return the message to the template you want. If you have custom form validation, you should do it in form class's `clean` method.

Please check django doc about [how to use form properly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/).

Comment: Your solution fixed the issue. Thank you Shang.